# Set a metadata field on MarkLogic 9.2 using the Management API

Tags: marklogic

I try to set a metadata field using the Management API on MarkLogic 9.2.  I send the following on port 8002:

```
PUT /manage/v2/databases/mydb/properties
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
{"field":[{"field-name":"foobar","metadata":""}]}
```

But I get a 500 in return, with the following message, complaining about `admin:database-set-field-metadata()` not being defined:

```
XDMP-UNDFUN: (err:XPST0017) xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin","database-set-field-metadata"))($config, $dbid, $field-name, $prop/fn:data(.)) -- Undefined function Q{http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin}database-set-field-metadata()
```

Note that setting the `metadata` property to `true` fails, the schema says it must be an empty string, but I doubt this is related.

Any idea how to set a metadata field using the Management API?

Comment: There were bugs related to this in 9.0-2. Can you upgrade to 9.0-4? You may need to use `"metadata" : "true"`, but you'll need 9.0-4 for that if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks, @grtjn. Unfortunately, whilst upgrading is in discussion, it is out of my hands and won't happen before weeks, at best. Any work around, maybe? The only one I can think of is to use the /eval endpoint and send the corresponding XQuery there...

Comment: BTW, in 9.4, I use `"metadata": true` (boolean, not string). Not sure it changes anything though.

Comment: Yes, /v1/eval is the suggested workaround..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Making a proper response to my own question, based on Geert's comments.  Thanks!

This is a bug in ML 9.2.  Upgrading to 9.4 would solve the problem.

If upgrading is not an option right now, sending an XQuery to be evaluated to the Client API on /v1/eval would indeed help you achieve the same result.